# Ошибка при разыменовании

Tags: c

```
struct treeNode {
    struct treeNode* leftPtr;
    int data;
    struct treeNode* rightPtr;
};

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;
typedef struct TreeNode* TreeNodePtr;

// insertNode получает: treePtr - NULL и value - 20
 
void insertNode(TreeNodePtr* treePtr, int value)
{
    if (*treePtr == NULL)
    {
        *treePtr = malloc(sizeof(TreeNodePtr));

        if (*treePtr != NULL)
        {
            (*treePtr)->data = value;
            (*treePtr)->leftPtr = NULL;
            (*treePtr)->rightPtr = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d not inserted. No memory available.\n", value);
        }
    }
}
```

Подчеркивает первые скобки ( "(" ) этих строк:

```
(*treePtr)->data = value;
(*treePtr)->leftPtr = NULL;
(*treePtr)->rightPtr = NULL;
```

Компилятор пишет:
**E0393 использование указателя на тип неполного класса не допускается**

Comment: Уберите все `*` в теле функции

Comment: В параметре, вы передаете указатель на структуру, и пытаетесь его разыменовать? Я думаю у вас там должен быть указатель на указатель, а не просто указатель.

Comment: В данную функцию я передаю адрес указателя @ヒミコ

Comment: Значит так и надо писать : `void insertNode(TreeNodePtr * * treePtr, int value)`

Comment: В данную функцию я передаю адрес указателя. TreeNodePtr - это указатель на структуру TreeNode. Так и получается, я передаю указатель на указатель, который уже указывает на структуру@ヒミコ

Comment: Я код в вопросе поправил. Посмотрите ещё раз пожалуйста. @AlexGlebe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых описка в имени структуры :

```
struct treeNode {
    struct treeNode* leftPtr;
    int data;
    struct treeNode* rightPtr;
};

typedef struct treeNode TreeNode;
typedef struct TreeNode* TreeNodePtr;
              ^^^
typedef struct treeNode* TreeNodePtr;
              или
typedef TreeNode* TreeNodePtr;
```

Во вторых память выделяется под указатель (это мало). Надо под структуру.

```
*treePtr = malloc(sizeof(TreeNodePtr));
                        ^^^
*treePtr = malloc(sizeof(TreeNode));
```